# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, nosuchmethod

I'm currently coding a Java application, but I got stuck.

```
package framework.messages.requests;

import framework.sessions.Session;

public class Handshake {
    
    public static void CheckRevision(Session Session) {
        try {
            System.out.println("[" + Session.GetID() + "] --&gt; " + Session.GetRequest().ReadUTF());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            
        }
    }  
}
```

Is what my class is.

In `main(String[] args)` if I use:

```
System.out.println(Handshake.class.getMethods()[0].getName());
```

Output is CheckRevision.

But if I use somewhere else:

```
this.Packets[6428] = Handshake.class.getMethod("CheckRevision");
```

I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: framework.messages.requests.Handshake.CheckRevision()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at framework.messages.MessageHandler.AddPackets(MessageHandler.java:18)
    at framework.Framework.main(Framework.java:34)
```

Why don't I get the good method?

Comment: You're going to have so many problems if you keep using uppercase naming for variables.

Comment: Why am I going to have many problems?

Comment: because it doesn't follow standard java naming conventions.

Comment: `Session.GetID()` Is `GetID()` a static method on the class `Session` or an instance method on the instance `Session`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you supply the `getMethod` method with only the method name, then it will assume that you are looking for a no-argument method.  The [`getMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...)) method has a varargs argument for the classes of the parameters of the method you're looking for.

Use

```
Handshake.class.getMethod("CheckRevision", Session.class);
```